# Compare two values (with a custom variable)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am comparing two values. For simplification,

I want to query what is in cell A in Table1 (let's call it Value1) and query what is in cell B in Table2 (let's call it Value2). I want to get the result, and then compare the difference.

Here's the catch:

Let's say Value1 = 1

Let's say Value2 = 9

The result of comparison needs to come back as 0

If Value1 = 1

If Value9 = 1

The result of comparison needs to come back as 100

If Value1 = 5

If Value9 = 9

The result of comparison needs to come back as 50

There are 4400 different combinations of 1 vs. 1, 1 vs. 2, and so on (already created in a spreadsheet, which I may need to put into a separate table for querying)

What is the best way to go about creating what I want to do?

Comment: Post create table statements here and some example data..

Answer (score 0):

If there is a function that determines the result, you could try and write it in SQL - alternatively why not store the lookup of results in another table and join against it?

Comment: Super late reply, but just a heads up:

I ended up accomplishing this through a PHP algorithm.